# surface triangulation to boundary representation

Tags: mesh-generation, gmsh

Are there any open source tools available which can take a surface triangulation of mesh volumes and convert them to a boundary representation?

I am interested in refining multiple region tetrahedral meshes with boundary conditions applied to some of the surfaces.  I have attempted to read a mesh into gmsh, but it is unclear what steps would be necessary to convert it to a boundary representation.

Comment: What do you mean by "boundary representation?" Do you want a list of the triangular elements on the boundary or something analytical? If the former, then this is possibly a duplicate of https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-to-recognize-boundary-nodes-and-sides-from-the-given-element-node-connectivi . If the latter, then you'll need to provide more detail about what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean something like what is described in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037704270500316X#